# Non-equi join with calculated column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to perform a non-equi join on two data.table where the comparison is made with the sum of two columns of the first data.table:

```
set.seed(2018)
DT1 <- data.table(ID =seq(10), X= round(500*runif(10)), Y= round(500*runif(10)));DT1
DT2 <- data.table(ID =seq(10), X_min =seq(0,900,100), X_max =seq(99,999,100), Text=LETTERS[1:10] );DT2
```

Now I would like to join the text from `DT2` that corresponds to the interval `[X_min, X_max]` that the sum `X+Y` from `DT1` is in. I could do:

```
DT1[, Z :=X+Y]
DT1[DT2, Description:=i.Text, on =.(Z>=X_min, Z<= X_max)]
```

is it possible to avoid calculating`Z`explicitly? This Fails:

```
DT1[DT2, Description:=i.Text, on =.((X+Y)>=X_min, (X+Y)<= X_max)]
```

Comment: As far as I know the columns have to be present in the data.table

Comment: okay, fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: There's a [FR#1639](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639) for this already. Just haven't gotten to it.